# Array and selection sort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, variable-assignment

My assignment asks me to make a simple Java program to take inventory for computer software. Design a program that will take user input for the name of the software and how many are in stock.

The program should then sort the items so that the records are in order by number of stock and display all of the records in numerical order.

I have to use two methods! A method to take user input and store in array and a method to sort in order from least to greatest and display!

Here's my code. I'm not sure what to do next. I'm not really sure how to sort it using the **selection sort**, but that's what I **need** to use. The one that's there is what I used from a lesson! I'm sure the *displayInfo* method is wrong, because I didn't know how to initialize any variables that weren't already used in the *inputInfo* method (I need the array and stuff). And it doesn't work when I call the *displayInfo* method in the main.

I hope that made sense. Wasn't really sure how to explain it...

Help, please!

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader; 
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ComputersRUs {
public static void inputInfo() throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader userInput = new BufferedReader  (new InputStreamReader(System.in));  
    System.out.print("How many softwares would you like to input? ");
    String software = userInput.readLine();
    int softwareNum = Integer.parseInt(software);   
    int[] softArray = new int[softwareNum];      

    String [] name = new String [softwareNum];
    int [] quantity = new int[softwareNum];       

    //loop through number of softwares  
    for (int i = 0; i < softwareNum; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Input name of software: ");
        String softwareName = userInput.readLine();

        name[i] = softwareName;

        System.out.println("Input quantity of software: ");
        String quantityString = userInput.readLine();
        int softwareQuantity = Integer.parseInt(quantityString);  

        quantity[i] = softwareQuantity;

        System.out.println("There are " + quantity[i] + " of the " + name[i] + " software.");
    } 
}

//method to sort and display info
public static void displayInfo(int[] arr)
{       
    //sort by quantity
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1; j<arr.length; j++)
        {
            if(arr[i] > arr[j] )
            {
                int temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = temp;
            }
        }
        //output
        for(i=0; i<=arr.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(arr[i] + "  ");
        }
    }
}

//main
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   //input
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    //loop to stop when user requests
    String quit = "n";
    while("n".equals(quit))
    {
        //display menu
        System.out.println("'COMPUTERS R US' Software Inventory - Main Menu");
        System.out.println("1) Input information");
        System.out.println("2) Display information in order");      
        System.out.println("3) Quit program");
        System.out.print("Please choose an option by inputting the number of your choice: ");
        String choiceString = br.readLine();
        int choice = Integer.parseInt(choiceString);

        if(choice == 1)
        { 
        inputInfo();
        }else if(choice == 2)
        { 
        displayInfo();
        }else if(choice == 3)
        { 
            System.out.println("Are you sure you want to quit? (y/n) ");  
            quit = br.readLine();
        }else
        { 
            System.out.println("Not a valid option."); 
        }                   
    }
}
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please take a look at how to ask homework questions (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). Your question is rather generic and you should try harder to solve the problem. `displayInfo` seems to some kind of bubblesort. If you have to use selection sort you should first take a look at the algorithm and then implement it: basically you have two sets (sorted and unsorted), sorted being empty in the beginning. You will then select the minimal element in the unsorted set and append it to the sorted set. Do this for every element.

Answer (score 0):

To help you with your sorting problem I recommend you read

http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/arrays/70sorting.html

As for initializing the Array why dont you send the array to your displayInfo using

```
displayInfo(softArray);
```

And then in displayInfo

```
public static void displayInfo(int[] arr){
int[] newSoftArray = arr;
```

You could then return the array with a return method